# Magento customer login page loads again straight after login and Frontedn cookie not getting created

Tags: php, magento, session, redirect, cookies

Magento (V 1.12) redirects me back to the Login page straight after a user logged in. If I look at requests list in Fierbug after pressing the login button it shows me,

```
http://dev.myweb/customer/account/loginPost/
http://dev.myweb/customer/account/
http://dev.myweb/customer/account/login/
```

So its going back to the login page. Even if I try to manually copy and paste the `http://dev.myweb/customer/account/` on the browser it goes back to the login page.

**Following line added after some debugging through the issue**

This happens because frontend cookie is not getting created when the session starts. Why its not getting created is the issue

This happens only on my local environment. It really frustrating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do this to resolve ...

Check the Cookie settings under System -> Configuration -> Web

```
Session Cookie Management
Cookie Lifetime = 3600
Cookie Path = (blank)
Cookie Domain = .yourdomain.com [this is (dot)yourdomain.com]
Use HTTP Only = Yes
```

Comment: Issue was the cookie domain. Thank you very much Kandrap.

Comment: I had the live site domain as the cookie domain. change it to my local and it works now.